# How to write file names of input file?

Tags: awk

I would like to print file name and number in first line in first column from 70 files. How to write input files? Thei names are hbe%05d.asc:

```
hbe00001.asc
hbe00002.asc
....
hbe00069.asc
hbe00070.asc
```

I tried and it is wrong:

```
awk 'NR==1{print FILENAME, $1}' hbe000[01-70].asc > max
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NR` (Number of Records) is a counter that monotonically increases, whereas `FNR` (Number of Records in the current File) is a counter that resets back to 1 at the first line of each file:

```
awk 'FNR==1{print FILENAME, $1}' hbe000{01..70}.asc > max
```

In bash, `{01..70}` expands to the sequence 01, 02, ..., 70.

Comment: Thank you and names of files are too wrong: `awk: fatal: cannot open file `hbe000[01-70].asc' for reading (No such file or directory)`

Comment: Thank you and how to print number in last row and first column? `awk 'END{print FILENAME, $1}' hbe000{01..70}.asc > min` - this command gives only result from the last file.

Comment: With GNU Awk, you can use `ENDFILE` instead of `END`.